# How to find where is the error in R shiny when debuger can't see it?

Tags: r, shiny

I have shiny app and get `ERROR: argument is of length zero` in the early begening. I was puting `browser()` everywhere to debug but nothing is shown.

This error occurs at `runApp`.

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted R and now it works. Very strange. :O